# Error: There are no commands defined in the "fos:user" namespace

Tags: php, symfony, command-line-interface, fosuserbundle

I am trying to [create a FOSUserBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/FOSUserBundle/command_line_tools.html) user using the command line tool:

```
php bin/console fos:user:create admin --super-admin
```

but I am systematically getting:

```
 There are no commands defined in the "fos:user" namespace.
```

Any ideas? I can see `CreateUserCommand.php` in `/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Command/`

**Update**

I have tried to delete `\vendor` and to run `composer install` again, but to no avail.

My `composer.json` has `"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0"`

**Finding**

Apparently, it is a known issue: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/pull/2639#issuecomment-361059568

Comment: Is the bundle enabled in your AppKernel?

Comment: Apparently, yes, in bundles.php (I am under Flex structure)

Answer (score 1):

remove `composer.lock` file and then run 
`composer install` again followed by 
`composer update` or `composer dump-autoload` commands.

Comment: Then probably your composer.json is not updated correct, try run composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0" again and then run composer install.

Comment: Are you using symfony 4?

Comment: No 3.4, since FOSUserBundle is not ready for 4 yet. The code has not been released. But I am under the Flex structure.

Comment: Yeah I get it, with Flex structure you probably don't need to update AppKernel file for Bundle entry.

Did you try running the command with sudo option? maybe it's permission issue.

Comment: @JVerstry did you do all steps mentioned in this document http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html And do you also have translator enabled?

Comment: Yes, but I had to make some adaptation for the Flex structure. Maybe I should wait until the 4.0 compatible release is coming out.